# how to give permission for particular web part?

Tags: web-part

How to show a `web part` for one particular user and hide it for others?

I know that we can use audiences but I don't know how to add users to the groups.

Answer (score 2):

**How to add users to the groups**

- Go to the site setting
- Click on Site permissions

Now you can create a new group from ribbon

[image]

OR click on a existing group and then click on **New**. You will find two options

- Add Users
- Add users to this group

[image]

Now come back to the **Target Audiences** property and enter your group name. You can press Ctrl+K to check name. Now click ok and save page

[image]

**PS:** User can not be added into target audience. Only groups can be. So add your users into a group first and then add the group in **Target  Audience**.

Comment: Please bother to comment in case of down vote. I have favorite quote **"Knives in a donkey's hand"**